# Open Source GIS Problem

Tags: pgrouting, open-source-gis, postgis-2.0, tilemill, mapnik

I am new at open source GIS platform. I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I have tried to install the followings but without 2-3 tools I could not install anyone. Can any body help me how can I install the following software from scratch. I mean dependencies on each other and installation priorities.

1. PostgreSQL
2. PostGIS
3. GDAL
4. GEOS
5. PROJ4
6. PGRouting (cgal & gaul)
7. Tilemill
8. Mapnik
9. Mod_tiles
10. QGIS

Comment: This question is too broad and not specific (which 2-3 tools?). Try using the Ubuntu package manager. That should help. And then come back with the ones that you have trouble with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you try the OSGEO Live DVD, check this [website](http://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html) for more information and download.